# How to Override A C System Call?

Tags: c, overriding, system-calls

So the problem is the following. The project needs to intercept all file IO 
operations, like `open()` and `close()`. I am trying to add `printf()` before calling the corresponding `open()` or `close()`. I am not supposed to rewrite the source code by changing `open()` or `close()` to `myOpen()` or `myClose()` for example. I have been trying to use `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. But the indefinite loop problem came up. My problem is like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797344/how-to-override-a-function-system-call-in-c-language).

```
int open(char * path,int flags,int mode)
{
    // print file name
    printf("open :%s\n",path);
    return __open(path,flags,mode);
}
```

Comment: What project? Intercept how? You really need tobe more specific here. Are you trying to make a library that can be linked in like the standard C one can be, or something that can latch on to any pre-compiled program?

Comment: Sort of a file io operation monitoring system. I need to keep track of all the file io operations made by a program. I cannot change other people's program. However, I have their source code. I am trying to make a library that can be linked in like the standard C. For example, I want to keep track of all the open() system call made by a program by defining a function name open() which print out a message first and then calls the real open().

Comment: Just use `strace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want `LD_PRELOAD`.

You need to create a shared library (`.so`) that has code for all functions that you want to intercept. And, you want to set `LD_PRELOAD` to use that shared library

Here is some sample code for the `open` function. You'll need to do something similar for each function you want to intercept:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

int
open(const char *file,int flags,int mode)
{
    static int (*real_open)(const char *file,int flags,int mode) = NULL;
    int fd;

    if (real_open == NULL)
        real_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"open");

    // do whatever special stuff ...

    fd = real_open(file,flags,mode);

    // do whatever special stuff ...

    return fd;
}
```

I believe `RTLD_NEXT` is easiest and may be sufficient. Otherwise, you could add a constructor that does `dlopen` *once* on `libc`

---

**UPDATE:**

> I am not familiar with C and I got the following problems with gcc. "error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)",

This is defined by several `#include` files, so try `#include <stdio.h>`. You'll need that if you want to call `printf`.

> "error: 'RTLD_NEXT' undeclared (first use in this function)",

That is defined by doing `#include <dlfcn.h>` [as shown in my example]

> and "symbol lookup error: ./hack_stackoverflow.so: undefined symbol: dlsym".

From `man dlsym`, it says: *Link with `-ldl`* So, add `-ldl` to the line that builds your `.so`.

Also, you have to be careful to prevent infinite recursion if the "special stuff" does something that loops back on your intercept function.

Notably, you want to call `printf`. If you intercept the `write` syscall, bad things may happen.

So, you need to keep track of when you're already in one of your intercept functions and *not* do anything special if already there. See the `in_self` variable.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

ssize_t
write(int fd,const void *buf,size_t len)
{
    static ssize_t (*real_write)(int fd,const void *buf,size_t len) = NULL;
    static int in_self = 0;
    ssize_t err;

    if (real_write == NULL)
        real_write = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"write");

    ++in_self;

    if (in_self == 1)
        printf("mywrite: fd=%d buf=%p len=%ld\n",fd,buf,len);

    err = real_write(fd,buf,len);

    if (in_self == 1)
        printf("mywrite: fd=%d buf=%p err=%ld\n",fd,buf,err);

    --in_self;

    return err;
}
```

---

The above works okay for single threaded programs/environments, but if you're intercepting an arbitrary one, *it* could be *multithreaded*.

So, we'd have to initialize all the `real_*` pointers in a *constructor*. This is a function with a special attribute that tells the dynamic loader to call the function ASAP automatically.

And, we have to put `in_self` into *thread local storage*. We do this by adding the `__thread` attribute.

You may need to link with `-lpthread` as well as `-ldl` for the multithreaded version.

**Edit:** We also have to preserve the correct `errno` value

Putting it all together:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int (*real_open)(const char *file,int flags,int mode) = NULL;
static ssize_t (*real_write)(int fd,const void *buf,size_t len) = NULL;

__attribute__((constructor))
void
my_lib_init(void)
{

    real_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"open");
    real_write = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"write");
}

int
open(const char *file,int flags,int mode)
{
    int fd;

    // do whatever special stuff ...

    fd = real_open(file,flags,mode);

    // do whatever special stuff ...

    return fd;
}

ssize_t
write(int fd,const void *buf,size_t len)
{
    static int __thread in_self = 0;
    int sverr;
    ssize_t ret;

    ++in_self;

    if (in_self == 1)
        printf("mywrite: fd=%d buf=%p len=%ld\n",fd,buf,len);

    ret = real_write(fd,buf,len);

    // preserve errno value for actual syscall -- otherwise, errno may
    // be set by the following printf and _caller_ will get the _wrong_
    // errno value
    sverr = errno;

    if (in_self == 1)
        printf("mywrite: fd=%d buf=%p ret=%ld\n",fd,buf,ret);

    --in_self;

    // restore correct errno value for write syscall
    errno = sverr;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-time reply. I am not familiar with C and I got the following problems with gcc. "error: 'NULL' undeclared (first use in this function)", "error: 'RTLD_NEXT' undeclared (first use in this function)", and "symbol lookup error: ./hack_stackoverflow.so: undefined symbol: dlsym". Any idea?

Comment: @Craig "From man dlsym, it says: Link with -ldl So, add -ldl to the line that builds your .so." and possibly by "unset LD_PRELOAD." This solved the problem. Thank you so much, Craig. You have been of great help. The world is a better place because of people like you.

Comment: I forgot that we also have to save/restore `errno`, so I've updated the final code block to reflect this.