# Tried to Override 'fopen()' But GCC Gave "error: conflicting types for 'fopen'"

Tags: c, overriding, system-calls

[My last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141254/how-to-override-a-c-system-call) as background.
I tried to wrap around "fopen()" but gcc gave me this error while "remove()" has no problem.

error: conflicting types for 'fopen'
fopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode)
^
In file included from file_io_operation_interception.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:272:14: note: previous declaration of 'fopen' was 
here
extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,

This is the code.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     8080
#define MAXLINE 1024

static int (*real_fopen)(const char *pathname, const char *mode) = NULL;
static int (*real_remove)(const char *filename) = NULL;
static int (*real_close)(int fd) = NULL;

__attribute__((constructor))
void
my_lib_init(void)
{

    real_fopen = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"fopen");
    real_remove = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"remove");
    real_close = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"close");
}

int
fopen(const char *pathname, const char *mode)
{
    int fd;

    // do whatever special stuff ...

    fd = real_fopen(pathname, mode);
    printf("open worked!\n");
    char message[200];
    char fidString[10];
    sprintf(fidString, "%d ", fd);
    strcat(message, fidString);
    strcat(message, pathname);
    sendMessage(message);
    // do whatever special stuff ...

    return fd;
}

int
remove(const char *filename)
{
    int ret;
    /*
    if (real_remove == NULL)
        real_remove = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"remove");
    */

    // do whatever special stuff ...
    printf("remove worked!\n");
    sendMessage("remove message sent");
    ret = real_remove(filename);

    // do whatever special stuff ...

    return ret;
}

int
close(int fd)
{
    int ret;
    /*
    if (real_close == NULL)
        real_close = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"close");
    */
    // do whatever special stuff ...
    printf("close worked!\n");
    ret = real_close(fd);
    // do whatever special stuff ...
    return ret;
}

int
sendMessage(char *message)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in     servaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int n, len;

    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)message, strlen(message),
        MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("message sent\n");
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

The "remove()" function works fine but the "fopen()" does not. Both of them are declared in stdio.h. However, why the difference?

Comment: See e.g. [this `fopen` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for the C99 declaration, which is different from yours.

Comment: Oh, and the error message actually *includes* the "correct" declaration. Why don'y you simply use it by copy-paste? The message is really clear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry but copy and paste what? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Look at your error message, especially when it says "note: previous declaration of 'fopen' was here". That shows the real declaration. Either copy-paste that (or the one from the reference I linked to earlier which uses the correct C99 keyword).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, I do not think that is the problem. Just now I tried using "const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode" but it did not work out. I am kind of overriding "fopen()", you see. GCC Error Message: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'filename'
 fopen(const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode)
                            ^
gcc: error: file_io_operation_interception.o: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you using an old version of gcc that doesn't default to gnu11 mode? If so, use the extension version of the restrict keyword like you see in the original error message.

Comment: @Shawn Is "gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)" OK?

Comment: @Shawn Could you elaborate on "use the extension version of the restrict keyword"? Thanks.

Comment: That's a really old gcc version, yes. And you should be able to figure out what to use by looking at the original type signature in the error message.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for replying. I contacted the system administrator and he said he was not able to upgrade it to newer versions. I just want to wrap around the original "fopen()" function, sort of overriding it. Is there any way to go around the gcc compile error?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The return value of "fopen()" should have been FILE *, instead I wrongly used int.